# Problems with saving excel file after importing data via macro

Tags: excel, vba, save

I want to insert data from source files in my excel model by opening the files and copying and pasting the values. I am just updating the values and not inserting formulas, formats or images etc.

The macro works fine and the inputs are pasted in my excel model. The last command is: ActiveWorkbook.Save

However, sometimes the macro cannot save the file (and I cannot see a regularity here - sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't) and it displays the error message: "Errors were detected while saving. Microsoft Excel may be able to save the file by removing or repairing some features. To make the repairs in a new file, click continue. To cancel saving the file, click cancel."

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this error? I am also posting the full code below. Thanks a lot in advance!

```
' Definitions
Dim i As Integer
Dim mapping_sheet, Worksheet_MVP, Dateiname_Input, Name_Worksheet_Input, Pfad_Input, Pfad_Datei, Zelle, Text As String


' Workbooks
Dim MVP, Auszug As Workbook


Pfad_Input = ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Value

Set MVP = ActiveWorkbook
Sheets("Automatisierung Datenupdate").Activate

Workbooks(MVP.Name).Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Workbooks(MVP.Name).Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False

' 1. Updating Macro

' Copy Pasting Data
If ActiveSheet.Range("E11").Value = "Ja" Then

          Dateiname_Input = ActiveSheet.Range("M11").Value
          Name_Worksheet_Input = ActiveSheet.Range("D11").Value
          Worksheet_MVP = ActiveSheet.Range("B11").Value
          Pfad_Datei = Pfad_Input & "\" & Dateiname_Input
          Sheets(Worksheet_MVP).Activate
          Range("B6:ZZ300").Select
          Selection.ClearContents
          Set Auszug = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Pfad_Datei)
          Workbooks(Auszug.Name).Activate
          Sheets(Name_Worksheet_Input).Activate
          Range("A4:ZY298").Select
          Selection.Copy
          Workbooks(MVP.Name).Activate
          Sheets(Worksheet_MVP).Activate
          Range("B6").Select
          Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
          
     
' Close and Save
          Workbooks(Auszug.Name).Activate
          ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Copy
          Workbooks(Auszug.Name).Close savechanges:=False
          Workbooks(MVP.Name).Activate
          Sheets("Automatisierung Datenupdate").Activate
          Range("M11").Select
          Selection.Copy
          Range("C11").Select
          Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
          
End If

' Save

Sheets("Automatisierung Datenupdate").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add your code? I did stop using activeworkbook as it has a tendency to be unpredictable vs specifically naming your workbooks.

Comment: Hi Ceci, thank you for your reply. 
I edited the questions with the code.  Would you recomment to specifically name the workbooks anywhere besides in the definitions?

Answer (score 0):

You mix up the concepts in your code which probably leads to the unexpected/irregular errors.

- If you don't specify a data type (or object type) when you dim, the variable is Variant by default. e.g. "Dim MVP" is the same as "Dim MVP as variant"
- You do assign your workbooks/worksheets to a variable but don't use the magic. Once set you can just refer to the workbook by referencing the varName.
- Although variables are very powerfull, when you just want to use cell values it's better to store these in memory (e.g. an array)

Hereunder an alternative approach, only using the named workbooks/worksheets and minimising the interactions with the sheet by using arrays:

```
Sub ceci()
    'dim vars to specific datatype
    Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, arr
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sh = wb.Sheets("Automatisierung Datenupdate")
    
    'To minimize the interactions with the sheet we store the data in memory, an array
    'here we can access each cell by referencing our array(<rowCounter>, <columnCounter>
    'e.g. arr(j,i) => if j = 1 and i = 1 we'll have the values of Cell A1
    'we can dump these values anywhere in the activesheet, other sheet, other workbook, ..
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet, wb2 As Workbook
    arr = sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value2 'assuming you have data as of A1 we store all in the array, you can fine tune if needed though
    If arr(11, 5) = "ja" Then 'E11
        'source wb
        Set sh2 = wb.Sheets(arr(11, 2)) 'b11
        sh2.Range("B6:ZZ300").ClearContents
        
        'wb2 - by specifically naming the workbooks and sheets we avoid unexpected errors
        Dim sh3 As Worksheet, arr2, Pfad_Datei As String: Pfad_Datei = wb.Path & "\" & arr(11, 13) 'arr(7, 2) & "\" & arr(11, 13) 'b7 & m11
        Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Pfad_Datei)
        Set sh3 = wb2.Sheets(arr(11, 4)) 'd11
        arr2 = sh3.Range("A4:ZY298").Value2
        
        sh2.Range(sh2.Cells(6, 2), sh2.Cells(UBound(arr2), UBound(arr2, 2))).Value2 = arr2 'dumb to sheet
        
        'wb1
        sh.Range("c11").Value = arr(11, 13) 'm11
    End If
    
    wb.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ceci, thank you very much for your response and explanation. So far I haven't encountered the error anymore.